# How to customize Access Token Lifetime Validator using AddIdentityServerAuthentication in WebAPI startup

Tags: identityserver4, access-token, jwt

I have a Web API protected with **IdentityServer4**. I want to use `AddIdentityServerAuthentication` extension method to setup protection because I know that it has some features like discovery document caching and so on. But I can't figure out how to customize `TokenValidationOptions` object to rewrite my custom **`LifetimeValidator`** just like the way you do using `AddJwtBearer` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customize your tokens in a API protected by IdentityServer, you can only customize them in the IdentityServer project it's self. [Here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/client.html#token) is the documentation part on tokens. Hope it helps and that i didn't misunderstand you.

EDIT: Maybe this will help:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        jwtOptions =>
        {
            // jwt bearer options
        },
        referenceOptions =>
        {
            // oauth2 introspection options
        });
```

Found [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation)

Comment: I'don't want to customize token. I just want to change way the WebAPI validate the token like you do in AddJWTBearer method.

Comment: Thanks, the object i need was in the third parameter ( oauth2 introspection options).